# Overcounting left cosets.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

There is something that I am missing in the proof of the Proposition:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be finite subgroups of a group $G$. Then
>    $$
>  |AB| = \frac{|A||B|}{|A\cap B|}.
>  $$

I will not reproduce the proof here, I just want to justify informally why this is true and then pose my question.

Clearly, $aB$ is a coset of $B$ and $|aB|=|B|$. Then if we calculate $AB$,
we are calculating all the cosets of $B$ that can be generated via $A$ (possibly we are overcounting). So $|AB|=n|B|$,  were $n$ has to be the total number of left cosets in $B$.
Then $n$ is proportional to $|A|$ *taking away* the overcounting. It happens that the overcounting are all those elements $a\in A$ such that $a\in A\cap B$.

Why $n=|A|/|A\cap B|$ and not $n=|A|-|A\cap B|$?

Answer (score 1):

You are not being sufficiently precise when you say "the overcounting are all those elements $a\in A$ such that $a\in A\cap B$".

The elements you are counting (and therefore overcounting) are not the elements $a$ but the products $c=ab$.  If $A\cap B$ has $n$ elements $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ with $a_1=e$, then any such product can be written in $n$ ways
$$c=(aa_1)(a_1^{-1}b)=(aa_2)(a_2^{-1}b)=\cdots=(aa_n)(a_n^{-1}b)\ .$$
I leave it as an exercise for you to see why $c$ can be written in **only** these $n$ ways.  So counting in this way gives every product $n$ times, and you have to divide by $n$ to get the correct count.

To understand the last step remember the old joke.  How do you count the sheep in a paddock? - Answer: count all their legs then divide by $4$.  OK, as a joke it's not very funny.  But it is something which will teach you some maths!!

Comment: The proof is by induction (in case you feel insecure) and it is proven in almost every abstract algebra/group theory book way before the question I am asking. I notice that you have problems, let me clarify them for your, yes I am referring to products of $a_1a_2\in A\cap B$. BUT $A$ is a group, so $a_1a_2$ is another $a$ in $A$ and there you have it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any relevance at all in that as a comment on my answer.  (E.g.: "the proof is by induction" - proof of what???) Was it maybe a reply to another comment which has now been deleted?